# parse a char vector to different strings

Tags: c++, parsing, vector, char, null-terminated

I have a character vector like

```
std::vector<char> input({'{', 'a', 'b','}',\0', '{','c','d','}',\0','\0','\0'});
```

I want to parse this to have strings

```
string1="ab"
string2="cd"
```

How to achieve this as vector has trailing '\0' characters.

Tried something like below. but going into infinite loop

```
td::vector<char> input({ 'a', 'b','\0', 'c','\0'});
std::vector<std::string> list;
std::string s(input.begin(), input.end());
size_t pos = 0;
std::string token;
while ((pos = s.find('\0')) != std::string::npos) {     
token = s.substr(0, pos);
s.erase(0, pos);
list.push_back(token);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but I doubt `s.find('\0')` should return the first occurrence of `\0`, which means that if string(assume a string) is `abcd\0ef`, `.find()` should return index 4. In this case, erasing 4 characters from position 0 means you are erasing `abcd` part of the string, while leaving `\0` still there. This is most likely causing the infinite loop.

To make sure, print the `pos` value to check what index it is before erasing.

Also, note that this approach will be quite slow, since `.erase()` is `O(n)` where `n=string.size()`, thus `.substr()` is also slow, with time complexity of substring size.